# Cant translate a string using Application context

Tags: android

My application uses a Foreground service to make sure the process is still running when app is removed from Recent list. So if the user kills the app by removing from that list, the application is still running in the background. In such state, some times, I need to show a background notification using the `NotificationManager`. The strings I use when showing the notification is obtained from `strings.xml`, according to the current selected device locale.
Currently, I use `Application` context to obtain the string from the `strings.xml` file and I pass it to the notification manager. 
The issue is, when using `Application` context to call `getString`, I only get the "default" english translation. Only when I use an `Activity` context, then I get access to the application resources and the correct translation is obtained. 
The problem is when a user kills the app, there is no `Activity` context to use. Only the `Application` context is available.

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!

EDIT 1:
I show the notification in this manner:

```
public void showNotification(){

   Context context = Application.getContextFromApplicationClass();
   Intent intent = MainActivity.getLaunchIntent(context);
        intent.putExtra(EVENT_NAME, eventName);
        notificationManager.notify(TRIP_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_ID, obtainNotification(getString(R.string
                .notification_event_title, eventName), getString(R.string.notification_event_message), false, false, getLaunchActivityPendingIntent(intent, TRIP_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_ID)));
        setCancellationAfterTime(TRIP_EVENT_NOTIFICATION_ID, 5000);
}
```

and this is the private getString() method I use:

```
private String getString(int resId){

        // First, attempt to use an Activity context to obtain possible language translations...
        Context activityContext = ((Application) Application.getContextFromApplicationClass()).getActivityContext();
        if (activityContext != null){
            return activityContext.getString(resId);
        }

        // If there is no activity, use the Application context that is running in the bg.
        return Application.getContextFromApplicationClass().getString(resId);

    }
```

So as you can see, the method showNotification(), when creating the Notification object, calls getString (which is a private method in the class). In it I obtain the Application context and from that I can get an Activity context if available.
If onDestroy was called on the activity at some point (such as when I remove the app from Recent list), I will no longer have access to that activity context and I will use the Application context instead.
but in such case, I cannot obtain the application resources and there is no translation.

Basically I'm looking for a solution on how to get translated strings for Notifications, when there is no Activity context present...

Comment: Can you add a code snippet from that service where you use `getString()`?

Comment: @cyborg86pl Hi, well, the Foreground service class is not the class that calls the NotificationManager. There is a whole system that runs in the background (even when app is killed) that does many things. One of them is detecting a certain state that should trigger a notification. That system does not have access to an Activity context when the app is removed from Recent list. It does have access to the Application context (it is saved statically when the Application is created).

Comment: I still can't figure out why getString serves default version of the string, but maybe instead of determining `Context` at service level, try to send it there from `Activity`.

Comment: Well, as stated, there is no Activity running. The app was removed from Recent list. The only available Context is the Application context...

Comment: What I meant was to try to send a reference to Activity's resources or context once when the Activity is created, then reuse those recources/context rather than determining context every time you ask for a string

Comment: I believe keeping a reference to an Activity like that, will cause a memory leak when the activity is destroyed (which happens when app is removed from Recent list).

Comment: You're right, it seems that I've been too long outside Android Development... But anyway, are you changing Locale programmatically somewhere, or you simply use the default one? What is Locale.getDefault() returning?

Answer (score 0):

Can you cast your application context to your activity?

```
Context actvitiyContext = this.getApplicationContext();
Activity activity = (Activity) actvitiyContext;
```

Comment: Who is 'this' referring to? If I obtain the Application context (statically), I cannot cast it to an Activity context. They are not the same thing...

Comment: how about getBaseContext() ? It returns context since every activity extends Context class

Comment: nope... that did not work either. It's not about the Context it is more about ContextThemeWrapper. The inheritance is different.